# SQL "COUNT" wrong results when JOINING more tables

Tags: sql, count, db2, inner-join

I have problem with my SQL query

I have

T1:

```
ID    STATUS   REPORTEDBY  
1     CLOSED   USER1
2     CLOSED   USER2
3     NEW      USER1
4     INPRG    USER1
5     CLOSED   USER1
```

T2:

```
T1ID  STATUS
1     NEW
1     CHECKING
1     CLOSED

2     NEW
2     CHECKING
2     CLOSED


3     NEW

4     CHECKING
4     INPRG 

5     INPRG
5     CLOSED
```

As result I want to get this:

```
USER    NumberHasCHECKING  NumberDifferentFromNewChecking  NumberClosed

USER1          2                         3                      2
USER2          1                         1                      1
```

I want to get as result group by REPORTEDBY field

1. number of records from T1 for which exist CHECKING status in T2,
2. number of records from T1 which is now in status differentg from NEW or CHECKING in T1
3. and number of records in T1 which is currently in CLOSED status in T1.

.

```
select reportedby,count (case when T2.status='CHECKING' then 1 end) as NumberHasChecking,
count (case when T2.status not in ('NEW','CHECKING') then 1 end) as NumberDifferentFromNewChecking, 
count (case when T1.status='CLOSED' then 1 end) as  NumberClosed
from t1
inner join t2 on T1.ID=T2.T1ID
group by reportedby
```

but after I do inner join I am getting much greater result for second and third column.
How to solve this?
thank you

Comment: Your query doesn't look like valid SQL.  Anyway, a join repeats all rows in the right table for all matches in the left table.  You can use subqueries or `count(distinct t3.id)` to count unique rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work on DB2:

```
Select 
  ReportedBy,
  Count (Case When t2.Status = 'CHECKING' Then 1 End) As NumberHasChecking,
  Count (Distinct Case When t1.Status Not In ('NEW','CHECKING') Then t1.Id End) As NumberDifferentFromNewChecking, 
  Count (Distinct Case When t1.Status = 'CLOSED' Then t1.Id End) As NumberClosed
From
  t1
    Inner Join
  t2
    on t1.Id = t2.t1Id
Group By 
  ReportedBy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    reportedby,
    sum (T2.CheckingState) as NumberHasChecking, 
    count (case when T1.status not in ('NEW','CHECKING') then 1 end) as NumberDifferentFromNewChecking, 
    count (case when T1.status='CLOSED' then 1 end) as NumberClosed 
from
    T1 inner join 
    (
        SELECT 
            T1ID,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='NEW'      THEN 1 END) NewState,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='CHECKING' THEN 1 END) CheckingState,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='CLOSED'   THEN 1 END) ClosedState
        FROM T2
        GROUP BY T1ID
    ) T2 ON T1.ID=T2.T1ID 
group by reportedby
```